# Why I don't see contollers when creating webapi in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webapi

I am trying to create WebAPI in visual studio code but I am not getting the controller!

in terminal:

```
dotnet new webapi -o WebAPI
```

I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHuxa.png)

Comment: I downloaded .net 8.0 is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add -controllers  or --use-controllers option.

```
dotnet new webapi -o WebAPI -controllers
```

OR

```
dotnet new webapi -o WebAPI --use-controllers
```

For more details refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#webapi.